# need excel formulae to display my data as below

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

my excel data as below:
[image]

and i want to merge data in Dept Name and Dept ID as like below.
[image]

Comment: You can use a combination of `TEXTJOIN` and `UNIQUE` as shown here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-into-one-keeping/8c3e83dd-7667-4f13-9495-15ac5b58043e

Answer (score 3):

**PowerQuery:**

- Change the type of 'Dept ID' to 'Text';

[image]

- Select 'Name' and 'ID', then under the 'Transform' tab, select 'Group By';
- Under 'Advanced', make sure to make the following aggregation:

[image]

- The errors don't matter. Now in the 'View' tab, got to 'Advanced Editor' and look up the pieces of code that say `each List.Sum(`. These need to be manually changed to `each Text.Combine( [Dept Name] , ";"), type text}` and `each Text.Combine( [Dept ID] , ";"), type text}`;
- Close and Load your data:

[image]

M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dept ID", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Name", "ID"}, {{"Dept Name New", each Text.Combine( [Dept Name] , ";"), type text}, {"Dept ID New", each Text.Combine( [Dept ID] , ";"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

**Excel 365:**

If this is something you need done with a formula, you can consider (using the same sample data as above);

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:B9),REDUCE(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,LET(a,INDEX(x,z),b,FILTER(C2:D9,MMULT(N(A2:B9=a),{1,1})=2),HSTACK(a,TEXTJOIN(";",,TAKE(b,,1)),TEXTJOIN(";",,DROP(b,,1))))))))
```

Comment: below formula is not working in Excel app on Windows machine. =LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:B9),REDUCE(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,LET(a,INDEX(x,z),b,FILTER(C2:D9,MMULT(N(A2:B9=a),{1,1})=2),HSTACK(a,TEXTJOIN(";",,TAKE(b,,1)),TEXTJOIN(";",,DROP(b,,1))))))))

Comment: @SANTHOSHKUMAR what version of Excel are you using? Try checking if each function used in that formula exists in your version. If it does not then consider updating.

Comment: i am using  below version and functions exists in the version. Version 2208

Comment: "Not working" is simply too vague as a response. Do you get an error? Did you translate the formula correctly? Does you version of Excel need semicolon instead of comma seperating parameters? @SANTHOSHKUMAR